# Whats the situational word for when someone gets effected by something they believed to be true?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: Someone was given a "coffee" and was told that it would energize them.
The person immediately feels the energizing effects of the "coffee" however, the "coffee" was actually just a can of regular (coffee-flavored?) Milk.

I remember there being studies on this but I just can't remember the name/word for this situation.

Comment: The [Placebo Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo)?

Comment: False advertisement.

Comment: The Placebo Effect is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Just a point on the headline of the question, you have confused the words 'effected' and 'affected'. 'Effected' means "carried out"; you actually mean 'affected' which means "changed". It's a very common error and easy to make as the meaning of the words 'effect' and 'affect' sometimes seem inconsistent.

Comment: Oops! Thank you for correcting my mistake, @BoldBen

Comment: They were ***conned***

Comment: There may be a problem with your question. The phrase "gets **effected** by" means "gets built by." What it appears you may actually mean is "gets **affected** by," which means "gets acted upon or influenced by." A person, for example, may be "affected" (verb) by what they believe to be true, whereas the outcome of being so affected, what being so affected builds, is an "effect" (noun). (e.g., Believing what she said was true **affected** him. Sadness and a strong urge to help her were **effects** that believing what she said was true had on him.)